# Sanitizer suboptions are enabled by default?

Tags: c++, llvm, address-sanitizer

LLVM's [Sanitizer documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html) says:

> Use clang++ to compile and link your program with -fsanitize=undefined flag. Make sure to use clang++ (not ld) as a linker, so that your executable is linked with proper UBSan runtime libraries. You can use clang instead of clang++ if you’re compiling/linking C code.
> ...
> You can enable only a subset of checks offered by UBSan, and define the desired behavior for each kind of check: ...

Does it mean that the subset of checks are by default included?

**For example, is `-fsanitize=undefined,alignment` redundant by having `alignment`?**

I have the same question about `-fsanitize=address` and also about GCC sanitizer.

I would like to enable as much sanitizers simultaneously as possible but I don't want to have unnecessary options in the command line or CMake line.
That is, I don't want to have `-fsanitize=address,pointer-compare,pointer-subtract,leak,shift,integer-divide-by-zero,unreachable,null,return,signed-integer-overflow` just in case.

**How such command line look like?**

The documentation is also not clear for the `ASAN_OPTIONS` runtime variable, it is not clear if things need to be activated or not.
For example, I have `ASAN_OPTIONS="handle_ioctl=true:check_initialization_order=true:detect_container_overflow=1:detect_stack_use_after_return=false:detect_odr_violation=1:allow_addr2line=true:strict_init_order=true"` but perhaps the `on/true` options are not really necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Sanitizers let you check for individual errors (`alignment`, `signed-integer-overflow`, etc.) and groups of errors:

- `address` - buffer overflows
- `leak` - memory leaks (implied by `address`)
- `undefined` - mostly integer Undefined Behavior errors
- `integer` - other suspicious integer behavior

(there are also `thread` and `memory` but let's not touch those as they are incompatible with Asan and UBsan and have to be run separately).

Contents of groups is documented in Clang documentation:

- https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html
- https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html

GCC *generally* tries to be compatible to Clang (for a noticeable exception of not supporting checking for `integer` errors).

In general I would suggest to use

```
-fsanitize=address,undefined,float-divide-by-zero,nullability \
-fno-sanitize-recover \
-fno-common \
-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE
```

(the `-fno-sanitize-recover` part is needed so that sanitizers abort your program whenever any check fails instead of continuing execution, the `-fno-common` [improves buffer overflow detection for global arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925754/why-address-sanitizer-doesnt-work-for-bss-global-overflow) and `-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE` disables source fortification which [prevents Asan from detecting some bugs](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/743)). You could extend this by

- adding `integer` to `-fsanitize` option (may report false positives for perfectly valid code in your program and libraries but this can worked around by using [ignorelists](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/SanitizerSpecialCaseList.html))
- adding `-fsanitize-address-use-after-scope` (may be too slow in your case)
- adding `pointer-compare,pointer-subtract` to `-fsanitize` option (tend be too slow for practical use)

For ASAN_OPTIONS you could check the default values in

- https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerFlags
- https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/SanitizerCommonFlags

I recommend to use the following set of options which enables some complex checks that are disabled by default:

```
export ASAN_OPTIONS='check_initialization_order=true:strict_init_order=true:detect_stack_use_after_return=true:strict_string_checks=true'
```

Now to your questions.

> For example, is -fsanitize=undefined,alignment redundant by having alignment?

Yes, it's redundant because `alignment` is included into `undefined`.

> That is, I don't want to have `-fsanitize=address,pointer-compare,pointer-subtract,leak,shift,integer-divide-by-zero,unreachable,null,return,signed-integer-overflow` just in case.

According to documentation your command line could be reduced to

```
-fsanitize=address,undefined,integer,pointer-compare,pointer-subtract
```

> For example, I have `ASAN_OPTIONS="handle_ioctl=true:check_initialization_order=true:detect_container_overflow=1:detect_stack_use_after_return=false:detect_odr_violation=1:allow_addr2line=true:strict_init_order=true"` but perhaps the on/true options are not really necessary.

According to docs your options could be reduced to

```
ASAN_OPTIONS='handle_ioctl=true:check_initialization_order=true:allow_addr2line=true:strict_init_order=true'
```

Comment: Thanks, "...could be reduced to ..." what about leak? What is the options by which I could enable the **maximum** number of (mutually compatible) checks. Of the ones you listed, which are the ones I can eliminate by having `leaks` added. From the first part of your answer I understand that it is simply `-fsanitize=address,leak,undefined,integer`, is it so?

Comment: `integer` seems to be incompatible with the GNU c++ library, since it detects errors in it (false positive hopefully?) `/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../include/c++/12/bits/random.tcc:416:33: runtime error: unsigned integer overflow: 397 - 624 cannot be represented in type 'unsigned long'
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../include/c++/12/bits/random.tcc:416:33 in 
`

Comment: @alfC "what about leak?" - Lsan is enabled by default with Asan, so `address` implies  `leak`.

Comment: "From the first part of your answer I understand that it is simply -fsanitize=address,leak,undefined,integer, is it so?" - not quite, some special checks are not included e.g. `pointer-compare` and `pointer-subtract` (they are very expensive) and also `float-divide-by-zero` and `nullability`. `bounds` is not included as well but all of it's checks are already covered by `address`.

Comment: @alfC "integer seems to be incompatible with the GNU c++ library" - yes, that's a known issue. You can work around this by disabling instrumentation of STL sources via [ignorelist](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/SanitizerSpecialCaseList.html).

Comment: ok, thanks for the data. One more iteration, is this complete now `-fsanitize=address,undefined,integer,pointer-compare,pointer-subtract,float-divide-by-zero,nullability`?  ("complete" in the sense that it has all the sanitizers that it can have at the same time).

Comment: Also, do I need to *activate* something with `ASAN_OPTIONS=`, or is it mostly to *deactivate* checks?

Comment: @alfC "is this complete now" - to my knowledge, yes.

Comment: @alfC "do I need to activate something with ASAN_OPTIONS" - the situation is the same as for `-fsanitize` flag: heavy checks are disabled by default so to enable them you require to set ASAN_OPTIONS. I typically use `ASAN_OPTIONS=check_initialization_order=true:strict_init_order=true:detect_stack_use_after_return=true:detect_odr_violation=1`.

Comment: @alfC And by the way it makes sense to also supply `-fno-sanitize-recover=asan,undefined,integer,float-divide-by-zero,nullability`, otherwise detected errors in these checkers will not cause your app to abort (only warning will be printed).

Comment: `-fsanitize=integer` can really mess with you when it's going after code with perfectly defined behavior - and it's still reported as "undefined". Only use this option if you _know_ that neither you nor the libraries you use (including the standard C++ library) will use wraparounds on unsigned integers. I would _not_ recommend using this option when using gcc's C++ standard library for example.

Comment: @yugr, "And by the way it makes sense to also supply...", isn't `-fno-sanitize-recover=all` for that?

Comment: Random note: I have to use `ASAN_OPTIONS="new_delete_type_mismatch=0:etc" otherwise it forces to have a virtual destructor even when it is not needed.

Comment: @alfC  _"otherwise it forces to have a virtual destructor even when it is not needed"_ - Is that on polymorphic classes used with shared pointers?

Comment: @alfC "isn't -fno-sanitize-recover=all for that?" - good catch! I've never used it myself, did it work for you?

Comment: @alfC "I have to use `ASAN_OPTIONS="new_delete_type_mismatch=0:etc"" - it's hard to comment without a reprocase, I think this should be a separate question.

Comment: `-fno-sanitize-recover=all`, yes it worked, it use to give the runtime analyzer warnings and continue.

Comment: @TedLyngmo "`-fsanitize=integer` can really mess with you when it's going after code with perfectly defined behavior" - thanks, that statement is true so I added a note in the answer. Still I believe this check is highly useful in practice even if user has to play a bit with [ignorelists](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/SanitizerSpecialCaseList.html).